# Razor DropDownListFor without passing model

Tags: razor, dropdownbox, dropdownlistfor

How to display this list

```
var dates = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Show offers for all dates", Value = ""},
    new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Show offers for today", Value = today.ToShortDateString()},
    new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Show offers for this week", Value = endOfThisWeek.ToShortDateString()},
    new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Show offers for this month", Value = endOfThisMonth.ToShortDateString()},
    new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Show offers for further out", Value = all.ToShortDateString()},
};
```

in

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor()
```

?

As far as I can see the DropDownListFor requires a model as a first argument but I don't require a model for the dropdown to work for my purposes.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
@Html.DropDownList("name", dates)
```

The `name` is the name of your dropdown (used in the `id` and `name` of the dropdown).

The `@Html.DropDownListFor()` is indeed for the cases when you have a model.